# PLACEHOLDER - How to get write_access to comment/answer on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, app, api-v2.2, placeholder, write-access

I'm trying to integrate the Stack Exchange API into my web app so I can fetch all posts as well as I can post answer or comments on them. I have successfully got `access_token` for **no_expiry** and **private_info** and they are working as well. But when I'm trying to get the `access_token` for **write access**, I'm getting an error as:

> Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write

Please let me know if anybody is also facing same issue or know how to get access token for **write_access**.

Answer (score 2):

Is your app listed [here](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/)? If so, you should edit its entry and paste the URL to this question in the field **Stack Apps Post (optional)**. If you don't have any apps there, you need to [create one](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) first and add the question later.